# play2-elasticsearch example is not working with play2.1.3

Tags: playframework, elasticsearch, playframework-2.1

I'm trying to use play2-elasticsearch plugin for playframework2 version 2.1.3 
I have just done exactly the github example says, the only modification was to change this line to use the server on the local ip address.

```
elasticsearch.client="127.0.0.1:9300"
```

but when i try to run the example i get the following exception, any idea? 
I'm using play framework 2.1.3 on mac with jdk1.7

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError]]
at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:289) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:383) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$play$core$server$netty$PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$handle$1$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:143) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$play$core$server$netty$PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$handle$1$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:139) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at play.libs.F$Promise$6.apply(F.java:401) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.liftedTree2$1(Future.scala:253) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:249) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:249) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:29) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.liftedTree1$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:67) ~[akka-actor_2.10.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
at com.github.cleverage.elasticsearch.Index.getIndexPath(Index.java:36) ~[play2-elasticsearch-0.5.4.jar:0.5.4]
at com.github.cleverage.elasticsearch.Index$Finder.<init>(Index.java:97) ~[play2-elasticsearch-0.5.4.jar:0.5.4]
at indexing.IndexTest.<clinit>(IndexTest.java:20) ~[na:na]
at services.HashThat.index(HashThat.java:35) ~[na:na]
at controllers.PostApi.addComment(PostApi.java:96) ~[na:na]
at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$20$$anonfun$apply$20.apply(routes_routing.scala:301) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.github.cleverage.elasticsearch.IndexService.<clinit>(IndexService.java:43) ~[play2-elasticsearch-0.5.4.jar:0.5.4]
at com.github.cleverage.elasticsearch.Index.getIndexPath(Index.java:36) ~[play2-elasticsearch-0.5.4.jar:0.5.4]
at com.github.cleverage.elasticsearch.Index$Finder.<init>(Index.java:97) ~[play2-elasticsearch-0.5.4.jar:0.5.4]
at indexing.IndexTest.<clinit>(IndexTest.java:20) ~[na:na]
at services.HashThat.index(HashThat.java:35) ~[na:na]
at controllers.PostApi.addComment(PostApi.java:96) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the stack trace, it seems that you use the `0.5.4` version which is not compatible with play 2.1.3 (only with play 2.1.0).

If you look at the ["versions" table](https://github.com/cleverage/play2-elasticsearch#versions) in the README file, you will see that the `0.7-SNAPSHOT` version is required if you use play 2.1.3. Try to use this one.